# Need help adding scroll bar to edit box

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2005, mfc, dialog, scrollbar

I'm making an MFC dialog-based application in Visual C++ 2005. I added a scroll bar to an edit box. How do I program the scroll bar to make it work?

Answer (score 1):

The windows styles wS_VSCROLL and WS_HSCROLL control if there is a scroll bar present or not.  Normally you just setup these styles as part of the resource dialog template.

With MFC you use the "[CWnd::ShowScrollBar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bcs3129s(VS.80).aspx)" method to turn the scroll bar on/off.

When scrollbars are turned on, then they should work automatically for edit controls.  You don't need to do anything.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.functionx.com/visualc/controls/scrollbar.htm

has code you can use to control the scroll bar.